# Python Pandas: Get Index Label for a Value in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Short question:

I have the following (sample) dataframe:

df:

```
        height   weight   hair
joe       5.6     123     brown
mary      5.2     110     blonde
pete      6.0     160     red
```

If I know the value in 'hair' is 'blonde', how do I get the index label (not integer location) corresponding to df.ix['mary','hair']? (In other words, I want to get 'mary' knowing that hair is 'blonde').

If I wanted the integer value of the index I'd use get_loc.  But I want the label.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the first label:

```
df[df['hair'] == 'blonde'].index[0]
```

Or if you want all the values:

```
labels = df[df['hair'] == 'blonde'].index.values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

I typically do the following using [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

idx = df.index[np.where(df['hair'] == 'blonde')]
```

Which gives the expected result:

```
Index([u'mary'], dtype='object')
```

If you want the result in a list, you can use `.tolist()` method of `index`